# MYSQL fetch array cannot catch row's name in php

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

Here is my code

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct s.doc_id, s.pat_id, s.approved, p.pat_fullname, p.pat_id from patient p, subscribe s WHERE s.doc_id = '$doc_id' AND s.approved = '1' AND s.pat_id = p.pat_id;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $patname = $row['p.pat_fullname'];      
    echo "<label>Patient:</label>";
    echo "<option value='$patname'>$patname</option>";

}
```

Notice: Undefined index: p.pat_fullname in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\PHR system\doc_patdoc.php on line 60

Above is the notice from browser. The sql query is definitely worked as I have tried it in my database. So what row's name should I put instead of p.pat_fullname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alias in your query :

```
p.pat_fullname as fullname
```

then access it like this :

```
$row['fullname']
```

You can access it without the `p.` table alias but if you have multiple columns with the same name this is the safest way to go

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I want.

Answer (score 5):

The result does not contain the `p.` prefix, so remove that:

```
 $patname = $row['pat_fullname'];
```

Comment: +1 this is a correct answer - but what if there are columns with the same name ? (I know there isnt in the OPs case, which is why I voted up)

Comment: If they are the same name, you need to alias them so that they have unique names.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith you mean just like my answer ;-)